# Lua Memory Control About Table

Tags: memory, lua, garbage-collection, lua-table

if I have structure like this:

```
tbl1 = {}
tbl2 = {}
tbl1.t1 = tbl2
-- release
tbl1 = nil
```

Then what is gonna happen to tbl2? Will it be released as well?

Comment: http://lua-users.org/wiki/GarbageCollectionTutorial

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Lua uses a mark and sweep algorithm for garbage collection, so unreachable yet circularly referenced data structures will be collected.

(In your code, it won't be released, as `tbl2` still contains a reference to the table, but I'm assuming you intended to clear that one too.)

Comment: if tbl1.a = ud1, and ud1 is a userdata type, will Lua add ref count to ud1?

Comment: @1hunch1kill Lua doesn't use reference counting. It uses mark and sweep. You don't have to worry about circularly referenced objects not being freed.